# Open excel file for manual edition and saving

Tags: c#, excel

It seems that most questions regarding working with Excel files through C# resolve around doing it in a fully automated way. I have a slightly different issue.

The way the code is supposed to work.

1. Launches a batch that creates a .txt file in given location, populated by results of a sql query. (Done and works)
2. Opens the file in Excel (the reason why I use .txt is that .csv messes up my numbers by removing leading zeroes etc) and makes it visible to the user. The code stops working and leaves the rest to the user.
3. User makes the changes to the file himself and manually saves them and exits Excel.

The problem that I am encountering is that the process does not want to 'leave the file alone'. It opens correctly, I edit the value and then I save it and when I try to close it it asks me if I want to save changes again. I click yes and that immediately brings up another popup asking the same question.

I do not know how to 'release' the file so that its control will be fully up to the user without actually closing Excel.

This is the bit of code that I use:

```
{
(...)
        RunBatch("Manual_adjustment");

        string fileName = "Manual_Adjustment.txt";

        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;

        excel.Visible = true;
     excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(ConstantValues.FolderPathInput + + @"\" + fileName);

     releaseObject(excelWorkbook);
     releaseObject(excel);
    }

private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

How do I let the user save the changes without making him manually open the file from the OS level?

Comment: you need to call Mashal.ReleaseComObject on all of the Objects that were created you are only releasing the workbook try doing the release on the `excel` object as well

Comment: releaseObject(excelWorkbook);
releaseObject(excel);
The second statement releases the excel object - or at least so I think - but it still makes no difference.

Comment: why make 2 calls when you can change the method signature to take both objects then call that in your method.. change your method to 
`private void releaseObject(object obj, object obj2)`

Answer (score 0):

I think calling to [Excell.Application.Quit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff839269.aspx) may works

Comment: I tried that and it closes my Excel window forcing the user to open the file manually.